# Retrieve more than 3 alias email addresses for contact using EWS API

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

Using the EWS Managed API, I want to query a list of contacts who are stored in the GAL in Exchange and get the list of alias email addresses for each contact.

It appears the only way to retrieve contact information from the GAL is by using the ResolveNames API call for each contact - is this correct?

Then for the result data that is returned for each contact, it appears that only 3 email addresses are returned - is there any way to get the full list of aliases attached to each contact?

Answer (score 0):

> > It appears the only way to retrieve contact information from the GAL is by using >>the ResolveNames API call for each contact - is this correct?

You can use FindPeople in Exchange 2013 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj191039%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx . However I believe GetPersona is also limited to only returning 3 email addresses. So if you need all the EmailAddresses you need to use either LDAP (you can get the ADGuid from ResolveName if you use the propertySet overload in 2010 eg

```
        PropertySet psPropSetaaaa = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
        NameResolutionCollection coll = service.ResolveName("glen", ResolveNameSearchLocation.DirectoryOnly, true, psPropSetaaaa);
        foreach (NameResolution nameRes in coll)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Contact name: " + nameRes.Contact.DirectoryId);
        }
```

) or use remotepowershell

Cheers
Glen

Comment: thanks for the answer. I tried using the FindPeople call but it was only returning 3 email addresses. Querying LDAP or using remotepowershell is not an option for us as we will be connecting to clients exchange server using the EWS endpoints

Comment: Then you will need to find another solution as EWS will only return the 3 addresses